Деплой телеграмм бота на node js + postgres
Написал бота на ноде, который выдает список фильмов (по жанрам и тд).
Бот берет фильмы из бд постгрес, сейчас хочу задеплоить его, причем так, чтобы бд не нужно было поднимать локально.
Как это реализовать?
Я правильно понимаю, что нужно создать докер файл, в котором будет инструкция для запуска бота и бд, причем чтобы не поднимать локально бд, нужно также создать файл с sql командами, которые при запуске контейнера добавят фильмы, а в будущем уже как то реализовать механизм обновления данных в боте (команда которая перечитает данные и обновит бд).

Всё в принципе верно. Только для базы не нужен Dockerfile, т.к. вы можете использовать готовый образ. Для развёртывания вашего бота и базы данных, Вы можете использовать Docker и Docker Compose.
Вот шаги, которые вам нужно выполнить:

Создайте Dockerfile для вашего бота на Node.js. Этот файл должен содержать инструкции по установке зависимостей и запуску бота.

Создайте файл docker-compose.yml. В этом файле вы определите Dockerfile или образ бота, а так-же образ базы данных.

Создайте файл с SQL-командами для инициализации базы данных. Этот
файл будет использоваться при первом запуске контейнера с базой
данных для создания таблиц и заполнения их данными. Укажите его в параметрах запуска контейнера база данных.


В будущем для обновления бд, вы можете разработать специальный интерфейс или автоматизировать выполнение данной задачи при помощи cron.
